# Issue with migrating a custom domain to a different API endpoint with AWS cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I'm following AWS instructions to migrate an edge custom domain to a regional: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-regional-api-custom-domain-migrate.html#update-edge-optimized-domain-name-to-regional-cli

```
aws apigateway update-domain-name \
    --domain-name 'api.example.com' \
    --patch-operations  [ \ 
        { op:'add', path: '/endpointConfiguration/types',value: 'REGIONAL' }, \
        { op:'add', path: '/regionalCertificateArn', value: 'arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:123456789012:certificate/cd833b28-58d2-407e-83e9-dce3fd852149' } \
      ]
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--patch-operations': Invalid JSON:
[
```

I will appreciate help. Thanks

Comment: Very strange syntax. Can you try with regular one: `--patch-operations op='add',path='/endpointConfiguration/types',value='REGIONAL' op='add',path='/regionalCertificateArn',value='arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:123456789012:certificate/cd833b28-58d2-407e-83e9-dce3fd852149'`?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks! That seemed to work. Now I'm stuck with the next one, which is removing the edge custom domain. The path is different than the other (it doesn't have the /), there are no values. Would you mind taking a look, please
`aws apigateway update-domain-name \
    --domain-name api.example.com \
    --patch-operations [ \
            {op:'remove', path:'/endpointConfiguration/types', value:'EDGE'}, \
            {op:'remove', path:'certificateName'}, \
            {op:'remove', path:'certificateArn'} \
        ]`

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you don't mind I will provide the answer for the first issue.

Comment: For the second issue, you are also using this "strange" syntax. Have you tried converting to standard one?

Comment: Yes. It is pretty weird. I tried with standard one and it fails. I was wondering it is because there are no values or because for example, `path:'certificateName'` has not a `/`

Comment: You could make new question specific to this new issue. Its difficult to infer what could be happening based on the comments only.

Comment: You are right as always. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was solved by using [Shorthand Syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-domain-name.html) for the `update-domain-name`:

```
aws apigateway update-domain-name \
    --domain-name 'api.example.com' \
    --patch-operations op='add',path='/endpointConfiguration/types',value='REGIONAL' op='add',path='/regionalCertificateArn',value='arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:123456789012:certificate/cd833b28-58d2-407e-83e9-dce3fd852149'
```